# Windows.Storage.Compression UnZip Compressed Folder

Tags: cordova, uwp, .net-core, compression

I am working on a UWP app that can only use .Net Core libraries. I have been trying to implement a zip/unzip tool. I have a few questions does Windows.Storage.Compression support the standard GZIP/ZIP file formats? I have written some test code to extract a ZIP i created in windows but it return a 0 byte length file.

```
var sourceFilename = "test.zip";
      var sourceFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(sourceFilename);

      var decompressedFilename = "test.xlsx"; // sourceFile.Name + ".decompressed";
      var decompressedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(decompressedFilename, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

      //Read the file stream
      using (var compressedInput = await sourceFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
      using (var decompressor = new Decompressor(compressedInput))
      using (var decompressedOutput = await decompressedFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
      {
        var bytesDecompressed = await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(decompressor, decompressedOutput);     
      }
```

As mentioned it returns a zero length file.

Further to this question I really want to develop a way to extract an existing zip (I have hundreds of them with thousands of items) using system.windows.compression into a folder of files. (I have this working fine in Android and IOS platforms but cannot see how to make this simple task with in UWP 10 (The system cannot use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile - due to Cordova UWP Windows 10 restrictions).

I have worked through https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Compression/js - which is where the file sample came from above but again cannot open a .zip made with Windows 10 or 7Z.

Answer (score -1):

> Further to this question I really want to develop a way to extract an existing zip (I have hundreds of them with thousands of items) using system.windows.compression into a folder of files. (I have this working fine in Android and IOS platforms but cannot see how to make this simple task with in UWP 10 (The system cannot use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile - due to Cordova UWP Windows 10 restrictions).

You can use [Cordova-plugin-zeep](https://github.com/FortuneN/cordova-plugin-zeep) to extract an existing zip file. Or you can create your own plugin leveraging `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` like [this](https://github.com/FortuneN/cordova-plugin-zeep/blob/master/src/windows/FiNeZeep/FiNeZeep.cs) for zip/unzip logic. For details, please refer to [Creating a Windows Plugin in C++ or managed code](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html#creating-a-windows-plugin-in-c-or-managed-code).

Comment: But under UWP Cordova 7 I was under the impression that only code in the .Net Core was available due to REMOTE mode. I tried using several modules that use ZipFile but all fail with library errors saying the libraries could not be found. What am I missing?